# Convert SASS to CSS using SASS gem

Tags: ruby, sass

I am trying to create a CSS file from SASS file.

I tried to do this at first.

```
sass_filename = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass"
css = Sass::Engine.for_file(sass_filename).render
File.open("#{render_path}/stylesheets/application.css", "wb") {|f| f.write(css) }
```

I got error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` on `Sass::Engine.for_file()` because [I didn't put anything for options field](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Engine.html#for_file-class_method).

I am not sure how I can set the options field.

I tried

`css = Sass::Engine.for_file(sass_filename, :syntax => :sass).render`

but I got `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` error.

How do I set the default option for converting SASS to CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not passing any options try using an empty hash, e.g. '{}', for options:

```
sass_filename = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass"
css = Sass::Engine.for_file(sass_filename, {}).render
File.open("#{render_path}/stylesheets/application.css", "wb") {|f| f.write(css) }
```

Comment: got the same error. `NoMethodError in PublishController#index 
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Which version of sass are you using? >= 3.1.15?

Comment: No, using 3.2.1. But it turns out, the problem was caused by collapsing `background` properties such as `background-color`, `background-image` and `background-repeat` into on single property in Sass. So I had to separate the properties up and it worked.